# Compare 2 columns in 2 different sheet and return 3rd value Vlookup

Tags: excel, excel-formula, vlookup

I have a sheet A like this:
[image]

And I have Sheet B like this:
[image]

Now I want to get the Result2 from sheet B and fill Sheet A result2 column by matching log & code

```
Sheet B Result2 =  Sheet A result2
```

How can I write the vlookup formula.
Please help me.

Thank you

Comment: If you've got 365 (and XLOOKUP) you can use something like `=XLOOKUP(A2 & B2,B!$A$2:$A$13 & B!$B$2:$B$13,B!$C$2:$C$13)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this really easy with SUMIFS because you are trying to get a number:

[image]

Formula in cell D2 from Sheet A is:

```
=SUMIFS('Sheet B'!$C$2:$C$8;'Sheet B'!$A$2:$A$8;'Sheet A'!A2;'Sheet B'!$B$2:$B$8;'Sheet A'!B2)
```

Another option would be using an array formula (it must be introduced pressing <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ENTER</kbd>+<kbd>SHIFT</kbd>):

```
=INDEX('Sheet B'!$C$2:$C$8;MATCH(A2&B2;'Sheet B'!$A$2:$A$8&'Sheet B'!$B$2:$B$8;0))
```